# Не работает angular material в angular 7

Tags: angular, angular-material

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: 'mat-checkbox' is not a known
> element:
>
> 1. If 'mat-checkbox' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. If 'mat-checkbox' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component
>    to suppress this message. ("
>
>    `<input matInput type="number" [(ngModel)]="id">`
>
>    `[ERROR ->]<mat-checkbox>1</mat-checkbox>`
>
>    `<button mat-raised-button (click)="getUser(id)">Выбрать юзера</button>`
>
> "):ng:///AuthorizationModule/AuthorizationPageComponent.html@3:2

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { SharedModule } from './modules/shared/shared.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AuthorizationModule } from './modules/authorization/authorization.module';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaterialModule } from './modules/material/material.module';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    AuthorizationModule,
    MaterialModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**material.module.ts**

```js
// Angular Material Components
import {MatCheckboxModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material';
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
import {MatAutocompleteModule} from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';
import {MatFormFieldModule} from '@angular/material/form-field';
import {MatRadioModule} from '@angular/material/radio';
import {MatSelectModule} from '@angular/material/select';
import {MatSliderModule} from '@angular/material/slider';
import {MatSlideToggleModule} from '@angular/material/slide-toggle';
import {MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu';
import {MatSidenavModule} from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import {MatToolbarModule} from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import {MatListModule} from '@angular/material/list';
import {MatGridListModule} from '@angular/material/grid-list';
import {MatCardModule} from '@angular/material/card';
import {MatStepperModule} from '@angular/material/stepper';
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material/tabs';
import {MatExpansionModule} from '@angular/material/expansion';
import {MatButtonToggleModule} from '@angular/material/button-toggle';
import {MatChipsModule} from '@angular/material/chips';
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import {MatProgressBarModule} from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatTooltipModule} from '@angular/material/tooltip';
import {MatSnackBarModule} from '@angular/material/snack-bar';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatSortModule} from '@angular/material/sort';
import {MatPaginatorModule} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

const modules = [
  MatCheckboxModule,
  MatButtonModule,
  MatInputModule,
  MatAutocompleteModule,
  MatDatepickerModule,
  MatFormFieldModule,
  MatRadioModule,
  MatSelectModule,
  MatSliderModule,
  MatSlideToggleModule,
  MatMenuModule,
  MatSidenavModule,
  MatToolbarModule,
  MatListModule,
  MatGridListModule,
  MatCardModule,
  MatStepperModule,
  MatTabsModule,
  MatExpansionModule,
  MatButtonToggleModule,
  MatChipsModule,
  MatIconModule,
  MatProgressSpinnerModule,
  MatProgressBarModule,
  MatDialogModule,
  MatTooltipModule,
  MatSnackBarModule,
  MatTableModule,
  MatSortModule,
  MatPaginatorModule
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [...modules],
  exports: [...modules]
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

**authorization.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AuthorizationPageComponent } from './components/authorization-page/authorization-page.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AuthorizationPageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ]
})
export class AuthorizationModule { }
```

Не работает ни один из компонентов material angular. Ставил сначала вручную (создал модуль, скачал material через npm), потом попробовал через ng add @angular/material - не помогло.

Comment: При этом, если вставить, например, mat-checkbox в app.component.html, всё работает. Судя по всему проблема где-то в зависимостях. Хотя, если я импортирую MaterialModule в app.module.ts, он не должен подключаться для всех дочерних модулей?

Comment: он должен подключаться во всех дочерних модулях, вернусь к своему любимому изречению - "читайте внимательно пожалуйста документацию" :)

Comment: @overthesanity благодарю. Сам методом тыка дошел до этого)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо было подключить Material Module в дочерние модули.